# × TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'currentUser' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication

For making the customized **Private Router** with respect to `currentUser` as given below the code:

**AuthContext.js:**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import {auth} from '../Database/Firebase';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

const useAuth = () => {
          return useContext(AuthContext);
}

const AuthProvider = (props) =>{
          const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({});
          const signup = (email, password) =>{
                    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
          }

          const login = (email, password) =>{
                    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
          }
          
          const logout =() =>{
                    return auth.signOut();
          }

          useEffect(() =>{
                    const unscubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) =>{
                              setCurrentUser(user);
                    });
                    return unscubscribe;
          }, []);

          return (
                    <AuthContext.Provider value={{currentUser, signup, login, logout}}>
                    {props.children}
                    </AuthContext.Provider>
          );
}

export { AuthProvider, useAuth};
```

**PrivateRoute.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import {useAuth} from "../UserAuthentication/AuthContext";

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
          const {currentUser} = useAuth();
          return (
                    <Route
                              {...rest}
                              render = {(props) =>{
                                        return currentUser ? (<Component {...props} />) : (<Redirect to='/login' />)
                              }} >
                    </Route>
          );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**Concern on the attached file to show the error:**
[image]

**Note:** I am tried to find this error but I should solved it and I think I can do it with the help of stackoverflow members.
Now, I have declare the `const {currentUser} = useAuth();` as objects and which is from `AuthContext.js` file with the same name. But why it's showed the error, I don't know.

Comment: Have you used `AuthProvider` somewhere higher in the tree than where you're using `PrivateRoute`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `AuthProvider` before you can use `useAuth`. Othervise the context value for it will be `undefined` and you will get the error as you see it.

Comment: Thanks for your instruction, it's solved.